# Problem in locating YYMMDD-HHMMSS.txt in Castalia Omnet++

Tags: omnet++

After running simulations in Castalia, I have got only one output file i.e. Castalia-
Trace.txt. However, as per the Castalia instructions manual, there should be another output file named as "YYMMDD-HHMMSS.txt".
Is there any method to enable that (YYMMDD-HHMMSS.txt) output file?

Comment: what's in the trace file? What other output did you get when running the command? Which Castalia version are you using. Please update the description of your question

Comment: I want to check number of packets recieved, num of sent packets etc. I am using Castalia 3.2.